# Get Path Parameters within Action Composition - Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have a route

`GET      /students/:id/edit controllers.StudentsController.edit(id: Long)`

and I want to do some validations before hitting the controllers itself

```
@With(ValidStudentIdAction.class)
public Result edit(long id) {
// ... edit stuff
}

public class ValidStudentIdAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
      long id receives the :id from request

      // now I know the id, I can verify if exist some Student with
      // this id, else return an error
      // ...

      return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

The problem is, how can I get the `:id` from the request ? calling `ctx.request()` returns  me `GET /students/{the id I want}/edit`, but the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/index.html) don't specify a way to get this `:id`. Is possible to get the `:id` in a portable way without doing some non portable regex ?

**note:** I'm not dealing with query parameters, the URL's are like `controller/id/action`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Not having access to the path parameters really reduces the possibilities of action composition.